# Using the method of fundamental solution to solve the heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve this question:

Use the method of fundamental solution to solve the heat equation $u_t = u_{xx}$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $t > 0$ and this initial data: $u(x,0) = e^{−|x|}$

I have done the method of fundamental solution, and the change of variables method, however I am unsure as to how to deal with the modulus in the initial data, and how this would change the calculation.

Comment: Did you try to split the integral into positive and negative part?

Comment: Why don't you show us your computations so we can see where the issue lies.